# Classify factor output with factors with >60 levels and numeric inputs

Tags: r, classification, multiclass-classification

I'm newbie, and working on a classification to see the causes of coral diseases. The dataset contains 45 variables.

The output variable is a factor with 21 levels (21 diseases) and the inputs are numeric and factor variables, and those factors have even 94 levels, those are like "type of specie of coral", so I can't get into a split factor because I want to be as precise as possible, so maybe one species is less resistant than another. So I can't split those factors. Numeric variables are such as, population in the area, fishing trips etc.

- First problem: tried genetic algorithms to select most important variables, random forests, etc., but... it gets aborted, so the variables I eliminated were just based on correlograms. I want something stronger to decide which variables select.
- Second problem: I've tried everything I know and made tons of searches on Google to find something that runs and make a classification, but nothing goes on. I tried SVM, Random Forests, Cart, GBM, bagging and boosting, but nothing can't with this dataset.

This is the structure of the dataset

```r
'data.frame':   136510 obs. of  45 variables:
 $ SITE                    : Factor w/ 144 levels "TUT-1511","TUT-1513",..: 56 15 55 21 12 12 17 53 48 82 ...
 $ Zone_Fine               : Factor w/ 17 levels "Aunuu_E","Aunuu_W",..: 11 9 10 9 9 9 9 8 10 10 ...
 $ TRANSECT                : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ SEGMENT                 : num  5 1 1 1 7 5 7 5 3 7 ...
 $ Seg_WIDTH               : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Seg_LENGTH              : num  2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 ...
 $ SPECIES                 : Factor w/ 156 levels "AAAA","AABR",..: 94 126 94 102 9 126 135 94 93 94 ...
 $ COLONYLENGTH            : num  11 45 10 5 12 10 8 30 20 14 ...
 $ OLDDEAD                 : num  5 2 5 0 0 5 10 0 5 10 ...
 $ RECENTDEAD              : num  0 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ DZCLASS                 : Factor w/ 21 levels "Acute Tissue Loss - White Syndrome",..: 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 ...
 $ EXTENT                  : num  52.9 52.9 52.9 52.9 52.9 ...
 $ SEVERITY                : num  3.11 3.11 3.11 3.11 3.11 ...
 $ TAXONNAME.x             : Factor w/ 155 levels "Acanthastrea hemprichii",..: 95 132 95 107 7 132 133 95 89 95 ...
 $ PHYLUM                  : Factor w/ 2 levels "Cnidaria","Rhodophyta": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ CLASS                   : Factor w/ 3 levels "Anthozoa","Florideophyceae",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ FAMILY                  : Factor w/ 20 levels "Acroporidae",..: 1 18 1 2 1 18 18 1 8 1 ...
 $ GENUS                   : Factor w/ 55 levels "Acanthastrea",..: 35 44 35 39 2 44 44 35 34 35 ...
 $ RANK                    : Factor w/ 2 levels "Genus","Species": 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ DATE_                   : Date, format: "0015-03-27" ...
 $ OBS_YEAR                : num  2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 ...
 $ REEF_ZONE               : Factor w/ 2 levels "Backreef","Forereef": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ DEPTH_BIN               : Factor w/ 4 levels "Bank","Deep",..: 2 2 4 3 2 2 3 4 3 3 ...
 $ LBSP                    : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Zone_Fine_ReefZone_Depth: Factor w/ 41 levels "Aunuu_E_Deep",..: 30 24 29 25 24 24 25 23 28 28 ...
 $ Area_km2.x              : num  50.9 49.1 101.8 49.1 49.1 ...
 $ Fishing.trips.per.km2   : num  719 1148 1431 1148 1148 ...
 $ Area_km2.y              : num  50.9 49.1 50.9 49.1 49.1 ...
 $ Pop.km2                 : num  167.5 49.1 561.9 49.1 49.1 ...
 $ SHED_NAME               : Factor w/ 35 levels "Aasu","Afao - Asili",..: 2 9 15 17 17 1 1 35 28 26 ...
 $ Shed_Cond               : Factor w/ 4 levels "Extensive","Intermediate",..: 3 4 2 4 4 3 3 3 1 2 ...
 $ Shed_Area_Calc          : num  30202 29422 458542 126361 32595 ...
 $ Perc_Area               : num  0.00128 0.00107 0.00993 0.00458 0.00118 ...
 $ Cond_Scale              : num  3 4 2 4 4 3 3 3 1 2 ...
 $ Shoreline_m             : num  23146 33046 45821 33046 33046 ...
 $ Rank                    : num  5 9 3 9 9 9 9 6 3 3 ...
 $ Comp.8                  : num  0.826 0.814 0.838 0.814 0.814 ...
 $ Ble                     : num  0.958 0.969 0.959 0.969 0.969 ...
 $ DZ                      : num  0.647 0.837 0.732 0.837 0.837 ...
 $ Herb                    : num  0.682 0.564 0.704 0.564 0.564 ...
 $ Rec                     : num  0.375 0.477 0.467 0.477 0.477 ...
 $ MA                      : num  0.965 0.975 0.907 0.975 0.975 ...
 $ Dam                     : num  0.998 1 0.992 1 1 ...
 $ TAXONNAME.y             : Factor w/ 94 levels "Abudefduf sordidus",..: 94 94 94 94 94 94 94 94 94 94 ...
 $ Dummy                   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I expected a classification of "DZCLASS".

Thanks, every recommendation is welcomed!

Comment: Can you send us your data? Sounds an interesting problem!

Comment: Instead of attempting to use variables with so many levels, have you tried converting them to dummy binary variables? Try the fastDummies package for this.